# How to declare a specific snippet in textmate {MAC}

Tags: macos, macros, textmate

i don't know if this is the right place, but i would know how to declare a new macro/snippet in textmate to do this :

I select the text

```
Sample Text
```

I use whatever combinaison of key and it transforms it into :

```
<?php echo __('Sample Text') ?>
```

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i manage to get this working :

by adding a new snipppet :D